# How is this integral operation called? $\langle f(x),\phi(x)\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\phi(x)dx $

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, terminology

Please, can someone tell what is the name of this operation in the context of Fourier analysis?

$$ \langle f,\phi \rangle := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\phi(x) \,{\rm d}x $$

And what is the meaning behind it?

Comment: It's an inner product, much like the dot product for real vetors.

Comment: In the context of distribution theory, it is called the "action" of the regular distribution T=[f] on "test function" ϕ

Comment: It is also an example of a "pairing".  See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2360350/442

Answer (score 1):

Consider $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$ and $L^2[a,b]:=\{f:[a,b]\to\mathbb C :\int_a^b\vert f(x)\vert^2dx<\infty\}$.
The sum and the multiplication for a scalar $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ are defined as
$$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x),\hspace{1.5cm}(\alpha f)(x)=\alpha f(x).$$
You can define an inner product $(\cdot,\cdot):L^2[a,b]\times L^2[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ as
$$(f,g)=\int_a^b \overline{f(x)}g(x)dx$$
and a norm
$$\Vert f\Vert^2=(f,f)=\int_a^b\vert f(x)\vert^2dx.$$
Hence you have a metric $\rho$ defined as $\rho(f,g)=\sqrt{(f-g,f-g)}$. When $-\infty=a<b=+\infty$ the space $L^2[a,b]$ can be written as $L^2(\mathbb R)$, which is an Hilbert space.
In the context of Fourier analysis these definitions are fundamental for the Fourier series of a function.
If $\mathcal H$ is an Hilbert space and $\Psi=\{\psi_k\}_{k\ge 1}$ is a basis for $\mathcal H$, the the Fourier series of a function $f\in\mathcal H$ is defined as
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k\psi_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\psi_k,f)_{\mathcal H}\psi_k$$
and in the case $L^2[a,b]$, the Fourier corefficients correspond to $f_k=\int_a^b \overline{\psi_k(x)}f(x)dx$.